# Regexp_replace to replace specific value

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have data in a column at different position which i want to replace using `regexp_replace()`.

Column value :

> Business solution, management services, credit Management services,
>   business solution, credit

I want to replace business solution with business solutions in a column nothing else I want to change..

Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
    SELECT
           REGEXP_REPLACE('Business solution, Business solutions, management services, credit Management services, business solution, credit'
          , 
'(^|[^[:alpha:]])business solution([^[:alpha:]]|$)','\1business solutions\2', 1, 0, 'i')

    from
          DUAL;
```

Comment: can you provide some examples where it is not working as long as your string is comma separated it should work

Comment: Row 1 ALLNET BUSINESS SOLUTIONS               row 2 ASSOCIATES, GBC, ALLNET BUSINESS SOLUTION.   ROW 3   CREDIT, ALLNET BUSINESS SOLUTION, ASSOCIATES.       In this Cas when I am trying this is not working

Comment: @JaspreetSingh Try the updated answer that should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace` in two ways.

**Case sensitive way:**

> ```
> SQL>
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      REGEXP_REPLACE('Business solution, management services, credit Management services, business solution, credit'
>   3      , 'business solution'
>   4      , 'business solutions')
>   5  FROM
>   6      DUAL;
>
> REGEXP_REPLACE('BUSINESSSOLUTION,MANAGEMENTSERVICES,CREDITMANAGEMENTSERVICES,BUSINESSSOLUTION,
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Business solution, management services, credit Management services, business solutions, credit
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Case insensitive way** by using `match_parameter` as `'i'`

> ```
> SQL>
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      REGEXP_REPLACE('Business solution, management services, credit Management services, business solution, credit'
>   3      , 'business solution'
>   4      , 'business solutions', 1, 0, 'i')
>   5  FROM
>   6      DUAL;
>
> REGEXP_REPLACE('BUSINESSSOLUTION,MANAGEMENTSERVICES,CREDITMANAGEMENTSERVICES,BUSINESSSOLUTION,C
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> business solutions, management services, credit Management services, business solutions, credit
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Not working in my case... I have business solutions and business solution both in the column however if I am trying to replace business solution with business solutions it is working but business solutions is also getting replace with business solutionss... Double ss is coming

Comment: have you tried the second one which works properly @JaspreetSingh